# ckeditor5 text-alignment plugin not working

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5

- I followed the installation steps for text alignment plugin as mentioned in the [docs](https://ckeditor5.github.io/docs/nightly/ckeditor5/latest/features/text-alignment.html#installation) of ckeditor5.
- Added the alignment plugin as below

> import Alignment from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignment';
>       ClassicEditor
>         .create(this.element.nativeElement,  {
>           plugins: [ Alignment ],
>           toolbar: [ 'alignment' ]
>       })

I am getting the below error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
    at IconView._updateXMLContent (iconview.js:100)
    at IconView.render (iconview.js:76)
    at IconView.on (observablemixin.js:241)
    at IconView.fire (emittermixin.js:196)
    at IconView.(anonymous function) [as render] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/src/observablemixin.js:249:16)
    at ViewCollection.on (viewcollection.js:68)
    at ViewCollection.fire (emittermixin.js:196)
    at ViewCollection.add (collection.js:182)
    at ButtonView.render (buttonview.js:160)
    at ButtonView.on (observablemixin.js:241)
```

Can someone help me how to tackle this? Followed the steps as mentioned in the docs but still having this issue.

Here is the complete angular5 component code for ckeditor:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, NgZone, ElementRef, ChangeDetectionStrategy, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import Alignment from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignment';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'ck-editor',
  template: '<textarea></textarea>',
  styleUrls: ['./ck-editor.component.scss'],
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CkEditorComponent),
    multi: true
  }],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CkEditorComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit, OnDestroy {

  onChange: Function;
  onTouched: Function;
  model: string;
  editor;

  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone,
    private element: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    ClassicEditor
      .create(this.element.nativeElement,  {
      plugins: [Alignment],
      toolbar: [
          'heading', '|', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'alignment', 'undo', 'redo'
      ]
    })
      .then(editor => {
        this.editor = editor;
        editor.model.document.on('change', () => {
          if (editor.model.document.differ.getChanges().length > 0) {
            this.ngZone.run(() => this.onChange(editor.getData()));
          }
        });
        editor.model.document.on('blur', () => {
          this.ngZone.run(() => this.onTouched());
        });
        this.editor.setData(this.model ? this.model : '');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.editor) {
      return this.editor.destroy();
    }
  }

  writeValue(value) {
    this.model = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

}
```

Comment: The error occurs because the object is not yet loaded when the method gets called.

Comment: hey, can you please explain me a bit more about what am I doing wrong.  I installed the plugin, imported it using import statement and mentioned the plugin in the plugins attribute while calling the create of ClassicEditor.

Comment: Please add your full code example for the community, so we can help you bettter.

Comment: @mthecreator, added full code of the component

Answer (score 4):

Choose custom build according to your requirement by clicking on below link

[CKEditor 5 Online Builder](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/)

**1.Choose plugins.** add Alignment plugin.
[image: Choose plugins]

**2.Drag and drop which plugins do you want to use in toolbar.**
[image]

**3.Download the bundle.**
[image: Download the bundle]

**4.Extract the zip** and copy the ckeditor.js file from build folder and paste it in node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build. Then, It will be replaced with whatever features you have choosen.**

**5.Install ckeditor5-alignment package** with version(whatever the version of @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic in package.json).

`npm i --save-dev @ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment@18.0.0`

**6.editor.component.html**

`<ckeditor [editor]="Editor" [config]="config"></ckeditor>`

**7.editor.component.ts**

```
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-editor',
  templateUrl: './editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editor.component.scss']
})


export class EditorComponent implements OnInit {
  public Editor = ClassicEditor;
  public config = {
    toolbar: {
      items: [
        'heading',
        '|',
        'bold',
        'italic',
        'link',
        'bulletedList',
        'numberedList',
        'alignment',
        'imageUpload',
        'blockQuote',
        'undo',
        'redo'
      ]
    },
    alignment: {
      options: ['left', 'right', 'center', 'justify']
    },
    removePlugins: ['MediaEmbed', 'Link'], mediaEmbed: {} //if you want to remove any plugin
  };

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Besides what I wrote in my second answer there's another issue in your code. It does not manifested itself yet, but it would if the editor had started.

The problem is here:

```
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import Alignment from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignment';
```

You cannot add plugins to an existing build like this. This will lead to an awful code duplication and runtime errors. The reason is that the build has already many plugins bundled in itself, so the whole core packages are included there too. The alignment feature depends on the core packages too so if you'll build it like this, the core packages will be included twice.

There's a separate guide how to [install plugins](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/development/installing-plugins.html) and I highly recommend reading it.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't configure webpack correctly. If you [build the editor from source](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/advanced-setup.html#scenario-2-building-from-source) (as opposed to using an [existing](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/overview.html#available-builds) or a [custom build](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/development/custom-builds.html)) you need to make sure that webpack is configured to handle CKEditor 5 assets. This includes handling CSS and SVG files as explained in [Webpack configuration](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/advanced-setup.html#webpack-configuration) section.

An example setup could look like this:

```
const { styles } = require( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils' );

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                // Or /ckeditor5-[^/]+\/theme\/icons\/[^/]+\.svg$/ if you want to limit this loader
                // to CKEditor 5 icons only.
                test: /\.svg$/,

                use: [ 'raw-loader' ]
            },
            {
                // Or /ckeditor5-[^/]+\/theme\/[\w-/]+\.css$/ if you want to limit this loader
                // to CKEditor 5 theme only.
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader',
                        options: {
                            singleton: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: styles.getPostCssConfig( {
                            themeImporter: {
                                themePath: require.resolve( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark' )
                            },
                            minify: true
                        } )
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Without the raw-loader handling SVG files, they are loaded as external assets so the editor gets their paths and not their XML source which breaks the editor.

PS. If you use Angular you may need to exclude CKEditor 5 files from the loaders that handle SVG and CSS by default.